# How to authenticate in MPMoviePlayer for iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to live stream my video files and play it in iPhone.

I am using MPMoviePlayer for playing the video.

I am specifying the url in the below API:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:theURL];
```

But my url asks for user credentials and I am not able to pass the credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem. It should be somehow possible by using NSURLCredential, but I wasn't able to figure it out until now.

Update: I figured it out, look at the documentation of MPMoviePlayerController, there you can see how it works.

For me it worked like this:

```
NSURLCredential *credential = [[[NSURLCredential alloc]
                                   initWithUser: kHTTPSUsername
                                   password: kHTTPSPassword
                                   persistence: NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession] autorelease];

    NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace = [[[NSURLProtectionSpace alloc]
                                              initWithHost: @"my.secret.host"
                                              port: 443
                                              protocol: @"https"
                                              realm: @"secret.host"
                                              authenticationMethod: NSURLAuthenticationMethodDefault] autorelease];

    [[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage] setDefaultCredential: credential forProtectionSpace: protectionSpace];
```